# ifelse shows warning based on the else function even when the test condition is met

Tags: r, if-statement, warnings, vectorization

I have a vector. For example,

```
a = c(5,-5)
```

I am wanting to perform different functions on the value of a depending on whether `a>0` or not

For simplicity, let's say the function is as follows

```
output = ifelse(a>0, log(1+a), 0)
```

This code returns the desired values in that output is equal to

```
1.791759 0.000000
```

However, it also shows the warning:

```
Warning message:
In log(1+a) : NaNs produced
```

I was hoping someone might be able to explain why this warning is displaying despite the fact that `log(1+a)` would only ever be called when `a>0` (which would not produce an NaN). Is this a weird quirk of `ifelse` or am I doing something wrong.

I will also note that this warning does not occur when both elements of a are less than 0 (e.g. `a=c(-5,-5)`)

Comment: I don't think you're doing something wrong. If you look at the examples in the docs `?ifelse`, you'll see there's a similar example with `sqrt()`. And besides, the output is as expected.

Comment: The `ifelse` evaluates the whole "yes" expression `log(1+a)` (if any part of the test is true) and then only picks those elemens where the test is true. But due to the evaluation it returns a warning.

Comment: @docendodiscimus my bad

Comment: If you want to avoid the warning, you can use `log(replace(a, a <= 0, 0) + 1)`

Comment: Alternatively you could do `log(ifelse(a>0, 1+a, 1))`

Comment: Thanks for those ideas. Unfortunately, the specific equation I am using is a bit more complicated than I posted. Specifically, `ifelse(a>0, log(1+a), -(log(1+a)+(log(1+a))^2))`. I don't think I can adapt your solutions to that specific equation.
I know it isn't good practice, but to avoid generating thousands of errors when I run this a large number of times, I am simply now using suppressWarnings(log(1+a))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quirky thing about the implementation of `ifelse`.

If we look at the function, we can see the part that is responsible for the actual output:

```
> ifelse
function (test, yes, no) 
{
    if (is.atomic(test)) {
        if (typeof(test) != "logical") 
            storage.mode(test) <- "logical"
        if (length(test) == 1 && is.null(attributes(test))) {
            if (is.na(test)) 
                return(NA)
            else if (test) {
                if (length(yes) == 1 && is.null(attributes(yes))) 
                  return(yes)
            }
            else if (length(no) == 1 && is.null(attributes(no))) 
                return(no)
        }
    }
    else test <- if (isS4(test)) 
        methods::as(test, "logical")
    else as.logical(test)
    ans <- test
    ok <- !(nas <- is.na(test))
    if (any(test[ok])) 
        ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & 
            ok]
    if (any(!test[ok])) 
        ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test & 
            ok]
    ans[nas] <- NA
    ans
}
```

This is the relevant part:

```
    ans <- test
    ok <- !(nas <- is.na(test))
    if (any(test[ok])) 
        ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & 
            ok]
    if (any(!test[ok])) 
        ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test & 
            ok]
    ans[nas] <- NA
    ans
```

The boolean result from `test` is stored in `ans`. Then there are some checks about whether there are `na` results, which is irrelevant here. Then the result vector is created based on the booleans. But look at the way that is done.

For the `TRUE` results:

```
ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok]
```

`yes` is evaluated and repeated so that it matches the output length, and then subsetted to take the items that were `TRUE` in the test.

The point where the warning is generated is right here. `ifelse` does evaluate `log(-5 + 1)`, generating the warning, but then excludes it from the result because `test = FALSE`.

Note that if all entries are `FALSE`, the if statement `if (any(test[ok]))` prevents the execution of that part, so there is no evaluation of the `yes` argument and no warnings.